# Transformar View em Bitmap sem usar buildDrawingCache()

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Eu tenho uma função que pega uma view e cria um bitmap. segue o código:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(Context context, View view) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

O Problema é que o "buildDrawingCache" aparentemente não funciona na API 28 (Android 9).
Existe alguma maneira de transformar a view em bitmap sem usar o "buildDrawingCache"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código é um pouco "estranho". Usa o `buildDrawingCache()` mas em vez de aproveitar o Bitmap que ele retorna, cria um novo e usa um Canvas para o preencher com o conteúdo da *view*.

Use apenas a parte que cria o Bitmap com as dimensões da View e um Canvas associado a ele. Depois peça à view que escreva o seu conteúdo nele.

```
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View view){

    //Cria um bitmap com as dimensões da view
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    //Cria um canvas para escrever no bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //Pede à view que escreva o seu conteúdo no bitmap, usando o canvas
    //anteriormente criado.
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Note que o método não pode ser chamado no `onCreate()`. Só após a "tree of views" ter sido criada é que a view tem o conteúdo e dimensões determinados.

Use-o no método `onWindowFocusChanged()`

```
private Bitmap viewBitmap;
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(viewBitmap == null){
        viewBitmap = getViewBitmap(View);
    }
}
```

ou num `OnGlobalLayoutListener`

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new

     ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
         @Override
         public void onGlobalLayout() {

            //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            viewBitmap = getViewBitmap(view);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Eu nem sabia da existência do `DrawingCache`, tanto que evitei dar uma resposta a pergunta. Acabei de ler na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) que esse cache é obsoleto desde a API 11 e seu uso pode comprometer a performance do aplicativo.

Comment: Funcionou tudo certinho, testei nas APIs 26,27,28 e em todas o código funcionou. Apenas para frizar o que o ramaral já tinha dito, não tentem usar esse bloco de código dentro do onCreate pois não funcionará.